# regex selecting multiple field

Tags: regex, pcre

From the following example pattern, I want to select the first 3 entries in the line.

Say:

1. timestamp
2. hostname
3. the first word after the hostname

Example pattern:

`2017-04-24T09:20:01.687387+00:00 aabvabcw74.def.co.uk hostd-probe: lacp: DEBUG]:147, Recv signal 15, LACP service is about to stop`

`2017-04-24T09:20:01.687387+00:00 aacdefabcw74.def.co.uk hostd-probe: lacp: DEBUG]:147, Recv signal 15, LACP service is about to stop`

I have used following regex and it worked fine.

REGEX 1 - ^(?:[^\s]*\s){1}([^\s]*) - to select the timestamp and hostname.
REGEX 2 - ^(?:[^\s]*\s){2}([^\s]\w+) - to select the word after the hostname.

`2017-04-24T09:20:01.687387+00:00 hostd probing is done Fdm: sslThumbprint>95:43:64:71:A3:60:D8:17:C8:6F:68:83:92:CE:E4:3B:53:4E:1D:AD10.199.6.5a2:0e:09:01:0a:00a2:0e:09:01:0b:01/vmfs/volumes/b01f388c-aaa4889f/vmfs/volumes/6ad2d8d7-86746df14435.5.03568722host-619286aabvabcs16.def.co.uk`

But the above log has created the problem, as it is not in a standard syslog format it has picked "hostd" as the hostname.

I would like to have regex which need to select the logs which has timestamp as the first entry, hostname as second entry (it always ends with.def.co.uk) and if it satisfies both then select the 3rd entry.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(\S+[^\s])\s(\w+\.def.co.uk)\s(.+?)\s` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/28dFPn/2)

**Break down :**

1. `(\S+[^\s])\s` capture out date and timestamp, and leave out the space after it
2. `(\w+\.def.co.uk)\s` capture only if it contains something.def.co.uk, and leave the space out again
3. `(.+)?` non greedily capture the first word (assuming *word* means no space in between

**EDIT :**

Unless you also want the date and time to be in their own capture groups, then it should be [like this](https://regex101.com/r/28dFPn/3):

`^(\S+)(T\S+)\s(\w+\.def.co.uk)\s(.+?)\s`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot SWLim, it worked. I forgot about the non-greedy capture.